# Login asp.net site with Scrapy using FormRequest.from_response not working despite matching requests

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to log in to the site https://signin.siemens.com/regpublic/login.aspx in order to view item availability on a connected domain. The site appears to accept the POST request, but it does not complete the login process and redirect to https://www.automation.siemens.com/ where it would display a 403 forbidden error, which is what I want (it still logs me in elsewhere). My form request payload appears to match the correct manual login request exactly, but it does not work.

I have also tried adding clickdata (both click and no click), formname, with no effect. It appears to be gathering cookies correctly. I have seen in similar posts that `__EVENTTARGET` is sometimes the culprit, however this site does not appear to generate an `__EVENTTARGET` in the final POST request, it remains an empty field. I also matched format exactly to the various successful post requests from manual completions. So now I'm not sure if it is targeting the form correctly.

```
def start_requests(self):
    login_url = "https://signin.siemens.com/regpublic/login.aspx"
    yield scrapy.Request(login_url, callback=self.login)

def login(self, response):
    logging.debug("starting login")
    req = FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        method="POST",
        formdata={
            "ctl00$GlobalScriptManager": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginUserNamePasswordUpdatePanel|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginUserNamePasswordButton",
            "__LASTFOCUS": "",
            "GlobalScriptManager_TSM": "",
            "__EVENTTARGET": "",
            "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
            "__VIEWSTATE": response.css(
                "input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)"
            ).extract_first(),
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": response.css(
                "input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)"
            ).extract_first(),
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": response.css(
                "input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)"
            ).extract_first(),
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextSiemensLogin": "EMAIL_USERNAME_HERE",
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextPassword": "PASSWORD_HERE", 
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdflLoginUserNamePassword": "1",
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginUserNamePasswordButton": "Login",
            "__ASYNCPOST": "true",
        },
        callback=self.start_scraping,
    )
    logging.debug(req.headers)
    logging.debug(req.body)
    return req
```

This is what the successful request looks like when logging in manually (with JavaScript disabled like with scrapy, it works fine with JavaScript disabled, but does not work with cookies disabled):

```
__LASTFOCUS: 
GlobalScriptManager_TSM: 
__EVENTTARGET: 
__EVENTARGUMENT: 
__VIEWSTATE: [VIEW-STATE-EXTRACT GOES HERE]
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: 93C9AE53
__EVENTVALIDATION: [EVENT-VALIDATION-EXTRACT GOES HERE]
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextSiemensLogin: [EMAIL_USERNAME_HERE]
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextPassword: [PASSWORD_HERE]
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginUserNamePasswordButton: Login
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdflLoginUserNamePassword:
```

I noticed that the request did not complete in scrapy unless `"__ASYNCPOST": "true"` was added back to the `formdata`, despite it not being present in the manual request. I am about to give up on using FormRequest and try with scrapy splash to simulate a manual completion. I'd be grateful for any insights offered before I do that instead.

Comment: There is code behind - written in c# or vb.net. And I suspect that code checks if the post-back came from the logon page, and did not originate from a different location. and there is also built in security in asp.net that checks if the page has been messed with, and thus once again, a post-back not originating from the actual site will not work. I mean, those who took a 3 day HTML course and think that any old post-back that does not originate from the actual site and think that will work? Think again, asp.net not simple kiddie script land, and is a far more complex system with moving parts

Comment: the only way you going to make this work is if you tools create a whole new separate instance of the browser as a COM automation object, and that means a real running copy of the browser is running, and one that hit the page, let it render, and then you enter the values. I mean, what copy of the encrypted view state you going to use here? (it will have to be the one that the page JUST created - not a outdated copy).

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Okay, I see, thank you for the comments. I'm not sure yet, I will update if I get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) script. It should be noted that while it worked correctly for the page in question, the Scrapy Splash browser was unable to render the pages generated with JavaScript on other login areas of the site despite it being enabled. This is the only page that it worked with.

```
lua_script = """
    function main(splash, args)
        splash.js_enabled = true
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(1))
        
        splash:send_text('[USERNAME]')
        assert(splash:wait(0.5))
        splash:send_keys("<Tab>")
        assert(splash:wait(0.5))
        splash:send_text('[PASSWORD]')
        assert(splash:wait(0.5))
        splash:send_keys("<Return>")
        assert(splash:wait(2))
        return {
            html = splash:html(),
            png = splash:png(),
            har = splash:har(),
        }
    end
"""
```